# Vertical Swipe / drag screens IOS / Phonegap

Tags: ios, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is it possible to create a vertical swiped screen change in Phonegap - (as in the Facebook app where you can swipe left to view notifications).

I would like to contain 5 pages within the main app - but also be able to swipe left to view a  separate page that contains a list of notifications / calendar items

Just wanted toi be sure this was possible before heading down that route..

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0):

So you essentially want scrolling but by page? You could use the jQuery Mobile scrollview to get the functionality http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/scrollview/scrollview-direction.html